# How to create sql query for the three tables in one statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating a little website. Assuming it has the following table

```
Table User
user_id | user_name
1       | a
2       | b
3       | c

Table Post
post_id | user_id (fk)
1       | 1
2       | 3
3       | 2
4       | 2

Table Block
block_by_user_id  | blocked_user_id (fk)
1                 | 2
```

I want to show all posts in the main page. For example current user is `user 1` this user must see all post except post from `user 2`, because user 1 blocked user 2 as you can see in the **Block** table.

Assume `$_SESSION['userid']` for current user session.
How the query should be? performance is considered.

Here is what i have tried so far, but i think it may not the best practice.
`select * from Post where user_id not in (select blocked_user_id from Block where block_by_user_id = '$_SESSION[userid]')`

I'm newbie. Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything??

Comment: You can use left join

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola I've updated my question, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: I like your query too (as Thorsten Kettner) - you're on the right way. MySQL optimizer can build correct plan for execution depends on statistics (with "left join" or with your "not in").

Answer (score 3):

The solution is:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p

LEFT JOIN blocks b
    ON p.user_id = b.blocked_user_id
    AND b.block_by_user_id = 1

WHERE b.block_id IS NULL;
```

You need to add a block_id to your blocks table. You join the blocked users and you filter them by block_id IS NULL. If you have questions just comment.

Comment: You missed one more condition in left join - `block_by_user_id = '$_SESSION[userid]'`

Answer (score 1):

Your own query is superior to the suggested answers in regards to readability - and this is what SQL is all about.

Stay with your query; it is perfect for the task, as it reads as it should: "select all posts except those from users that are blocked by the current user".

Comment: Actually @Marcus updated here just an example, suppose he need user name in his query then he has to join user table also..Also if block user table grow then not in with sub query will slow query as it is mysql even in mssql it is fine....

Comment: @Zafar Malik: Well, okay, if they want to see users, then the users table must be joined, naturally. And yes, if MySQL is not capable of dealing with a simple IN clause, then you would have to re-write the query one day. Don't know when this would be necessary. When blocks exceed 10,000 rows? Or 10 millions? Don't know. On the other hand, by that time the MySQL engine may have improved. Only use tricks when issues force you to. I see no need for an obfuscated query, as long as a straight-forward query would run fine.

Answer (score 0):

check it-

```
SELECT usr.user_id,pst.post_id 
FROM users AS usr 
JOIN posts pst ON pst.user_id=usr.user_id 
LEFT JOIN block blk ON usr.user_id=blk.blocked_user_id 
WHERE blk.id IS NULL;
```